# Problemas al recoger los datos mediante select

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo un problema al hacer un simple select de una fecha. Os comento:

Quiero recoger el mes de la creacion de un archivo y que este ordenado por la fecha con esta sentencia:

```
select  to_char(fecha,'MONTH') as MES from archivos order by (fecha)  asc;
```

El problema es que hay varios archivos creados el mismo mes y me muestra esto:

```
SEPTIEMBRE
SEPTIEMBRE
OCTUBRE   
OCTUBRE   
NOVIEMBRE 
DICIEMBRE 
DICIEMBRE 
DICIEMBRE 
DICIEMBRE 
ENERO
```

solo quiero que me salga un mes, no todos. He encontrado algo sobre el `select distinc` pero me da error... Tambien creo que se puede hacer con `group by`.

Tambien he probado con `distinc`

```
 select distinct(to_char(fecha,'MONTH')) as MES from hph_weekly order by fecha asc;
```

pero me da este error:

```
01791. 00000 - "not a SELECTed expression"
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: @lois6b este es el error que me da `01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"` cuando utilizo esta sentencia  `select distinct(to_char(fecha,'MONTH')) as MES from hph_weekly order by fecha asc;`

Comment: ya esta editada, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  
    distinct(to_char(fecha,'MONTH')) as MES 
from 
    archivos 
order by to_number(to_char(to_date(mes,'mm'),'mm'))  asc;
```

En la select se obtiene los meses como texto to_char del campo fecha con formato MONTH (nombre del mes completo), y se usan el distinct para evitar duplicados.

En el order by se coge el mes y se convierte a número del 1 al 12 para ordenar de Enero a Febrero (no se puede usar el nombre del mes al ser alfabético).

Comment: Me da error tu sentencia `ORA-01791: no es una expresión obtenida bajo SELECT
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 9, columna: 28`

Comment: Lo he modificado

Comment: ahora si, perfecto! muchas gracias